# Simplify Ruby methods: leave unnecessary variables off

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, dry, simplify

When I write methods in Ruby I often think "I bet this could be done simpler". Here is one example method. It adds all numbers starting at 1 until the number `n`. Is there a way to leave off the variable `solution`?

```
def sum n
    solution = 0
    for i in 1..n do
        solution += i
    end
    solution
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (or [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)):

```
(1..10).inject :+
# => 55
```

Comment: i think **(1..10).inject(:+)**

Comment: @rejin, In Ruby, you can omit parentheses unless the expression is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

falsetru's is the shorthand answer for sum. But just to expand on that for your own benefit, `inject` normally looks more like this:

```
def sum n
  (1..n).inject {|result, i| result + i}
end
```

In this example, the result of the block is fed back in as `result` with each successive iteration, so it builds a cumulative total.

`inject` is very versatile, but there are plenty of other iterators which save you from managing a count variable. Look up `times`, `each` and `map` for starters.